# using tailwind globals and reset file is imported but not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

app/globals.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

app/layout.tsx

```js
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import '@/app/globals.css';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

app/page.tsx

```js
import FullScreenBox from '@/src/_test_/mock/components/fullScreenBox';
import { sortOfTailwindOrder } from '@/src/_test_/mock/static/sortOfTailwindNumber';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <p className="text-xs underline">dd</p>
      <div>
        {sortOfTailwindOrder.map((order: number) => (
          <FullScreenBox key={order} order={order} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

tailwind.config.ts

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        white: '#EFEFEF',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

as you can see in layout.tsx file, globals.css is imported so that my project does not have any margin and padding. but `text-xs underline` in page.tsx is not working at all. There are classnames i set thru editor shown up in developer tool (F11) but no style applied. How can I resolve this?

Funny fact is that my tailwind code is running properly in my storybook files.